# Syntax of generating an object Data for use as functional argument leading to error

Tags: c, function, pointers

We have a typedef *int Data, i am trying to create a generator function

```
Data data_gen(int idata){
  Data d = malloc(sizeof(idata));
  d = &idata;
  return d;
}
```

However when I pass this function as argument to another function which requires Data as an argument I recieve the following error, method makes pointer from an integer without a cast, which suggest that my method data_gen is returning an integer as opposed to a data object.

```
typedef int* Data;
```

I am calling this function with data_gen and receiving error:

```
void bstree_insert(BStree bst, Key key, Data data);
```

where the third argument is call of data_gen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixes the bug in your generator function:

```
Data
data_gen(int idata)
{
    Data d = malloc(sizeof(*d));

    *d = idata;

    return d;
}
```

A `typedef` for this function would be:

```
typedef Data (*data_function)(int);
```

Then, your tree function would need to be:

```
void bstree_insert(BStree bst, Key key, data_function gen);
```

So, right now you're mixing up a simple pointer (i.e. `int *`) with a pointer to a *function* that returns an `int *`. These are not the same thing.